# Styling Material UI components using CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a Material UI component, and I am trying to custom style it using the CSS.

Following is the code:

```
<IconButton className="my-class">
    <Close />
</IconButton>
```

CSS:

```
.my-class {
  float: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

But I am not able to style it, when I tried the following, it works:

```
<IconButton style={{ float: 'right', marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: '0' }}> 
    <Close />
</IconButton>
```

Why I am not able to style the Material UI components using regular CSS?

Comment: Spend some time you should learn how to customize the MUI components. https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#main-content

Answer (score 5):

Most CSS-in-JS solutions inject their styles at the bottom of the HTML `<head>`, which gives MUI precedence over your custom styles.
You need to use the `StyledEngineProvider` exported from `@mui/material/styles` with the `injectFirst` option, in order for the CSS injection order to be correct. It is explained [here](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order).

So something like this shoud work:

```
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <IconButton className="my-class">
      <CloseIcon></CloseIcon>
    </IconButton>
</StyledEngineProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style MUI components using several ways like [GlobalStyles API](https://mui.com/api/global-styles/#main-content), [sx](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content), [styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content) or even normal way.

If you are going to style the particular component like IconButton, and if you have a look at the [document](https://mui.com/api/icon-button/#css) for the API, you can find the class names for the component.

Here's couple of references.
https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#main-content

[How to give conditional style to MUI TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459413/how-to-give-conditional-style-to-mui-textfield/70459457#70459457)